# How to add multi-location select map in angular2 application?

Tags: angular

I am working on an angular2 project in which I have requirement to show map with following functionality :

1) Map will be divided according to postal codes.
2) Click on map will highlight that whole postal code area in map.
3) After click it will return the postal code of highlighted area.

Any suggestions from any one that how can I do it.